# Danish localization broken in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, nslocalizedstring, nslocale

I've seen other threads about the simulator, but I'm experiencing a 90% break which is nothing short of miraculous.

Our app is localized in 5 languages. All of them work perfectly, except Danish.

Only certain words are translated, even though all of them use the shortcut "NSLocalizedString". Also, the BarButtonSystemItem "Back" and "Cancel" both work.

The symptoms are exactly the same in the simulator, device, iOS 7 & 8. I've also tried both "Danish" (da) and "Danish (Denmark)" (da-DK) in different combinations.

Is anybody else experiencing weird localization issues like this?

Comment: Sometimes, cleaning your Xcode project makes miracles happen

Comment: Yeah, did that, deleted Derived data folder, deleted apps, restarted phone. No difference.

Comment: I know it's going to turn out to be some stupid mistake I made, but when all the other languages work perfectly, I can't figure this out.

Comment: If nothing seems to work you may want to completely remove the danish localization (after backing it up) from the app and then add it like you did with the other languages. I know that it's a lot of work, but again, if you can't figure out what's wrong, that will probably be the best thing to do.

Comment: By the way, i've experienced this once with german localizations. Did everything to solve it, but nothing worked. Removing the localizations and adding it again worked for me

Comment: Removed Danish localization, cleaned, cleaned build folder, deleted derived data folder, deleted app and re-added danish localization only to get the exact same result. Am I going crazy? Enabled string debug and got the following error: "Localizable string "Rating" not found in strings table "Localizable" of bundle CFBundle"

Comment: That's very weird. I think you are making a very small error somewhere that is hard to find.
Try this:
- Make sure you have named the file "Localizable.strings" ( I once named it Localization.strings..)
- The cause could be a missing semi colon or quotation mark.

Comment: Also, check if you have more than one Localizable.strings in your project. Merging them into one may solve your problem

Comment: Found the error, check the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I knew it would be a stupid bug, but this one takes the prize.

In the danish Localizable.strings file, an EMPTY ROW had a SPACE CHARACTER in it.

I'm not kidding.

This made the app find all the translations up to the space character, then nothing after it... OMG what a stupid parsing error bug from Apple.

File a bug anyone? *facepalm*

Comment: I'm glad you finally solved your issue!
And yeah, you might consider it to be a bug. It is extremely weird that one misplaced space ruins your entire localization... Have a nice day!

Comment: XCode really is a mess.